# Why does Terminal change tabs on Cmd-1

Tags: terminal, keyboard, mojave

If I look at the Window menu in Terminal, it lists a shortcut to switch to my first tab as `Option+Cmd+1` (and second with ...+2, etc). However, both `Option+Cmd+1` and `Cmd+1` switch to my first tab.

Is it possible to change this behaviour so only the listed command works? I'm trying to remap `Cmd+9` and `Cmd+0` to cycle tabs, but `Cmd+9` doesn't work -- it's trying to switch to the 9th tab (whether it exists or not).

My System Preferences > Keyboard > Shortcuts > App Shortcuts menu lists only my cycle tabs commands. (And they show up in Terminal's Window menu.)

macOS 10.14.3